# Override react mui select dropdown style

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, dropdown

I'm using the react mui Select Component for forms and now for language select
my problem is for the language Select I need a different style for the dropdown I can do it by overriding the relevant class but the problem is it will happen to every Select and I want it only for the language Select as you can see in the photo:

[image]

and here my code:

```
const LanguagesSelect = props => {

  return (
    <Select  className="test" classes="assad" style={{ position: "relative !important", left: "20px !important", top: "30px !important", width: "168.3px !important", background: "white !important", borderRadius:"12.75px" }} >
      <MenuItem className="menuTest" style={{ paddingLeft: "5px" }}>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", width: "100%" }}>
          <img src={require("../../../assets/img/icons/flags/franch.svg").default} />
          <div style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }} >Franch</div>
        </div>
      </MenuItem>

      <MenuItem className="menuTest" style={{ paddingLeft: "5px" }}>
        <img src={require("../../../assets/img/icons/flags/eng.svg").default} />
        <div style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>English</div>
      </MenuItem>

      <MenuItem className="menuTest" style={{ paddingLeft: "5px" }}>
        <img src={require("../../../assets/img/icons/flags/turkish.svg").default} />
        <div style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>Turkish</div>
      </MenuItem>

      <MenuItem className="menuTest" style={{ paddingLeft: "5px" }}>
        <img src={require("../../../assets/img/icons/flags/czech.svg").default} />
        <div style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>Czech</div>
      </MenuItem>

      <MenuItem className="menuTest" style={{ paddingLeft: "5px" }}>
        <img src={require("../../../assets/img/icons/flags/hebrew.svg").default} />
        <div style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>עברית</div>
      </MenuItem>

    </Select>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sx prop to override the default style.
here's a link for more description [mui_sx_prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/)

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to work with this prop. I made an example stackblitz.com/edit/react-hw6sxz?file=demo.js can you please show me which changes have to be done

Answer (score 0):

You can give external css to the `Select` element and manipulate the child (MenuItem) from there.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to do that. I made an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hw6sxz?file=demo.js can you please show me which changes have to be done?